# how to write a two same query at a time at a one place

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

SELECT sum(amount) AS paid Amount FROM transaction WHERE status = '1' and user_id ='10' AND SELECT sum(amount) AS unpaid Amount FROM transaction WHERE status = '0' and user_id ='10'

Comment: is there any other status other than '1' and '0'?

Comment: no other status

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `CASE` statements? Here's a [link](https://learnsql.com/blog/case-when-with-sum/) to a resource you may want to take a look at.

```
SELECT user_id,
  SUM (CASE WHEN status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PAID_AMOUNT,
  SUM (CASE WHEN status = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as UNPAID_AMOUNT
WHERE user_id='10'
FROM transaction
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: i have a transaction table their is a amount, status and tasker id  feild.  status 1 for paid amount and status 0 for unpaid amount. if tasker id  6 and their are ex. 5 paid amount and 5 unpaid amount so i want different result such as paid amount is 15000 and unpaid amount is 10000 for a particular tasker id 6.

Comment: Hmmm. I see, when you say "it's not working", were there error logs when you ran the SQL? Also what database are you using? PostgresQL? MySQL?

Comment: I am using MySQL